# How to update a field in collection1 when inserting in collection2 in MongoDB using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am developing a software by C# and MongoDB. I have two collections "Students" and "StudentsRequests". I want to update the `FirstRequestDate` field in collection "Students" when a student sends his/her first request to collection "StudentsRequests". How can I do that? IS that possible by using `$setOnInsert`?
My data is as below:

```
Student:{ 
_id:123456,
"Name": "John Doe",
"StudentNumber": "ED147852",
"RequestCount": 0,
"FirstRequestDate": Null,
"LastRequestDate": Null
}

StudentRequests:{ 
_id:123456,
"Title": "my request",
"StudentNumber": "ED147852",
"Description": "description",
"Date": Date("2018-05-30")
}
```

And the code is as below:

```
StudentRequestCollection.InsertOneAsync(StudentRequestObj);
```

When inserting `StudentRequestObj` in `StudentRequestCollection` I want to update `FirstRequestDate` in `StudentCollection`. I dont know if it is first request or not. I want to do that only if it is the first request.

Comment: What kind of collections are you using? Do you know if this is a 1st request or is that part of the problem? In other words, I need more information. What have you tried and how has it failed. Share code.

Comment: @Mary I updated my question with more details. I hope it shows better what the problem is.